# How to add new cells to a fixed UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to get new cells with data from a NSManagedObject to a tableview with a fixed section.

The first section is a fixed section. The second section is where the user can add new data. Displaying the fixed section separate is no problem, as well as showing the dynamic content separate. But when I combine them, I get stuck with this method (see below at the 'rows = ???'). Normally you can fix this easily by doing [array count] but my ManagedObjects are not collected in an array.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
//return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
 NSInteger rows = 0;

 switch (section) {
  case FIXED_SECTION:
   rows = 4;
   break;
  case LIST_SECTION:
  {
   rows = ???;
   break;
  }
  default:
   break;
 }
 return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either collect the `NSManagedObject`s in an array (probably an instance variable of the view controller subclass you’re using) or maintain a counter that you increment when adding a cell and decrement when you remove a cell.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you need, the manual section explains pretty much as you need it